# How use "IS NOT NULL" in select() method of ActiveRecord in yii2?

Tags: yii2

Hi I have some table with column 'geom' which contain large data. When I make Model by this table I need select all columns without this 'geom' col. Wanna just check contain this col something or not and write true or false value of the col.
Like this in SQL:

```
SELECT geom IS NOT NULL FROM tableName;
```

I tried this:

```
`$model = self::find()
        ->select(['([[geom]]) IS NOT NULL'])
        ->all();`
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: It looks like you have problem with writing SQL query. Could you describe what output do you want from SQL and try to add tag sql.

Answer (score 2):

```
$model = self::find()
->select('geom')
->where(['NOT', ['geom' => null]])
->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by this command:

```
$model = ClassName::findBySql('SELECT leshoz_ru, geom IS NOT NULL AS geom FROM leshoz')->all();
```

Comment: keeb0-  You should probably get used to the notation that pLe0mAx put and not rely on findBySql, once you get used to it's it's pretty obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DB expression](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-expression) like follows:

```
$expression = new Expression('geom IS NOT NULL');
$model = self::find()
    ->select($expression)
    ->all()
```